# Get the value of a variable from release definition in this ReleaseApprovalPendingEvent.xsl file

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

My requirement is to customize the Release Approval Pending emails. For this, I am modifying ReleaseApprovalPendingEvent.xsl file.

Now My problem is that I don’t find any method to get the value of a variable from release definition in this ReleaseApprovalPendingEvent.xsl file.

Comment: Please be to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the ReleaseApprovalPendingEvent.xsl file to customize the format of email notifications, but you can not modify the content.

You could try the existing [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task or customize your own email alert.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own TFS server plugin to subscribe the "ReleaseApprovalPendingEvent" and send email with the content you want. Or you can create a service hook and create a web service to monitor the service hooks and then send out email.